# Manually load UITextField

Tags: ios, uitextfield

*Is there any way to initalize/load a UITextField (in a UITableViewCell) before the cell is visible onscreen? The user must scroll down to see the cell, and if the user does not scroll down, the textfield is never loaded. How can I manually load it, to ensure that it is present, regardless of the user's decision to scroll or not.*

**EDIT**

I fixed the problem, I was confused as to what I needed to do, but realized that I had just mistyped some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, because if a UITableViewCell is not scrolled down to, it doesn't even exist. Cells are created on demand as their rows are scrolled into view, and are then reused as *other* rows are scrolled into view. It is meaningless to speak of populating a nonexistent object, nor would you have reason to do so.

Remember, what's important is not the cells, but the *model*, the data that they represent. If you need info, look in the model. *That* is what is prepopulated. If your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is correctly written and your model is correctly structured, you'll have no problem populating any row's cell on demand in real time.

Answer (score 0):

From what it appears you are attempting to accomplish, you may be duplicating what

```
dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(_:)
```

does.  This takes care of queuing/dequeuing the cells (and loading the views inside of the cells). Please take a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:

Can you provide a bit more info?